# Elements collapsing in bootstrap4 navbar even when not required

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I recently tried to crate a Whatsapp similar UI using bootstrap.So i used Bootstrap Navbar.And it works fine. But when i resize the window the navbar content comes on new line, i want to restrict that. For example the "Status" has a Dot with it. On resizing the  window the dot moves to next line. How can i restrict that.(try on 867 x 811)

Here is is the link [Whatsapp UI Practice](https://thakur-raj.github.io/whatsapp/)
Have a look at the screenshot.[image: Screenshot]

And here is my navbar code :

Whatsapp

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Chats

                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="status.html">Status
                    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 11px;">brightness_1</i>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="calls.html">Calls</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">
                    More
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" id="moreOptions">
                    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">New group</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">New broadcast</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">WhatsApp Web</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">Starred messages</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="profilePage.html">Settings</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0 mr-sm-2" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**U have to change some of the CSS**

```
@media(max-width:991px){
   .navbar-nav > li {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
   .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Tahseen ur Rehman , That worked !!! Can you help me to understand that . Why it worked ?

Comment: Im asking, because instead of simply copy and pasting solutions. I should understand them in first place.

Comment: when you minimize padding from 20 t0 10 and from 8 t0 0 then the entire content got more space

Comment: So is that 20 and 8 . the default padding size ? Sorry if my questions are silly.